# Powershell access works but AzureCliCredential fails with "Principal X is not authorized"

Tags: c#, .net, azure, polyglot-notebooks

In a Polyglot Notebook in VS Code, after

```
az login --tenant xyz
```

I can

```
az iot hub device-twin show --hub-name 'hub1' --device-id 'John' --query 'properties.desired' --output json --subscription 'sub1'
```

This is great.

Sadly, when trying to get the twin using c# I cannot get any of the AzureCredential`s providers to work. For example:

```
var hub = "hub1.azure-devices.net";
var deviceId = "John";


var credential = new AzureCliCredential(new AzureCliCredentialOptions { TenantId = "xyz", }); 

var rm = RegistryManager.Create(hub, credential);

var twin = await rm.GetTwinAsync(deviceId); // This fails
```

fails with:

> Error: Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common.Exceptions.UnauthorizedException: {"Message":"ErrorCode:IotHubUnauthorized;Principal <edited>@<edited>.com is not authorized for GET on /twins/John due to no assigned permissions","ExceptionMessage":"Tracking ID:abc:0-TimeStamp:06/26/2023 07:44:12"}

The error is the same when trying with `InteractiveBrowserCredential`.

Using a connection string works:

```
var rm = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString("HostName=hub1.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=abc=");
            
var twin = await rm.GetTwinAsync(deviceId); // This works
```

Q: Can I authenticate to Azure with my personal account using `AzureCliCredential`/ `InteractiveBrowserCredential`?

---

The included libraries are:

```
#i "nuget:https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet5/nuget/v3/index.json" 
#i "nuget:https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-tools/nuget/v3/index.json" 

#r "nuget:Azure.Identity"
#r "nuget:Microsoft.Extensions.Azure"
#r "nuget:Microsoft.Azure.Devices"

using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error:Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common.Exceptions.UnauthorizedException: {"Message":"ErrorCode:IotHubUnauthorized;Principal @.com is not authorized for GET on /twins/John due to no assigned permissions","ExceptionMessage":"Tracking ID:abc:0-TimeStamp:06/26/2023 07:44:12"}

The above error occurs when you don't have the proper role to access the device id using credentials.

You need to use **`IoT Hub Data Contributor`** role for your user and you can use the [Defaultazurecredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#defaultazurecredential) to fetch the twin using c# .

**Role:**
[image]

Used the same code with Defaultazurecredential and it executed successfully.

**Code:**

```
 using Azure.Identity;
 using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;
    
    
    var hub = "<your-hub-name>.azure-devices.net";
    var deviceId = "<your-device-name>";
    
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    var rm = RegistryManager.Create(hub, credential);
    var twin = await rm.GetTwinAsync(deviceId);
    Console.WriteLine(twin.DeviceScope);
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "$metadata": {
    "$lastUpdated": "2021-08-11T05:22:12.3717129Z"
  },
  "$version": 1
}
```

[image]